# Are there any ASP.Net MVC reference applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to learn ASP.Net MVC framework and I was wondering if there were any good reference applications that I could use to learn about implementing ASP.Net as well as best practices for implementing LOB apps.

If possible I would like to see a ASP.Net MVC app that uses AJAX too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NerdDinner
http://www.codeplex.com/NerdDinner

MVC Storefront
http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples

KIGG (MVC implementation of Digg running at dotnetshoutout.com)
http://www.codeplex.com/kigg

Oxite
http://www.codeplex.com/oxite

Code Camp Server
http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/

CarTrackr
http://www.codeplex.com/CarTrackr

StackOverflow (no source of course)
http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: +1 for KIGG.  Very comprehensive unit testing in this project!

Answer (score 4):

[Nerd Dinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/)

[Code and Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) available as a free chapter from ASP.Net MVC 1.0 Book by [Conery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151/rob-conery), [Hanselman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman), [Haack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598/haacked), and [Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) (couldn't find SO user page)

[Source code also available](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at NerdDinner?

[ScottGu' blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-1-0.aspx)

also

[the html tutorial for the Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[Oxite project (an open source blog engine)](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite)

There are however opinions that it is not that good an example to learn from:

[Oxite - Oh Dear Lord Why?!](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/12/15/oxite-oh-dear-lord-why.aspx)

Comment: That was before the did a large refactoring, the code base is in far better state and would night recommend checking it out as how an Mvc app. should be done.

Answer (score 0):

[CarTrackr](http://cartrackr.codeplex.com/) is a simple sample app from the book [ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Quickly](http://www.packtpub.com/asp-net-model-view-controller-1-0-quickly/book).